# Linear transformations: one-to-one mapping.

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

My Linear Algebra textbook offers the following theorem:

> Let $T: R^n \to R^m$ be a linear transformation. Then $T$ is one-to-one if and only if the equation $T(\vec{x})$ = $\vec{0}$ has only the trivial solution.

I don't understand why this is true.

From discrete mathematics, I know that a mapping/function $T: A \to B$ is one-to-one if, for $a \in A$ and $b \in B$, we have that $f(a) = f(b)$ implies that $a = b$. In other words, no two elements in the domain map to the same element in the codomain.

In terms of vectors, that means that no two vectors $\vec{x}$ in the domain $R^n$ map to the same vector $A\vec{x}$ in $R^m$. Or in other words, $A\vec{x} = \vec{b}$ has at most one solution for all $\vec{x} \in R^n$.

In the theorem they give, why are they only talking about $\vec{b} = \vec{0}$, the zero vector?

What if $T(\vec{x}) = \vec{b}$ has infinitely many solutions for $\vec{b} \ne \vec{0}$, violating the condition for one-to-oneness?

I don't see why only examining the special case of $T(\vec{x}) = \vec{0}$ can allow us to conclude that the entire mapping is one to one.

**Edit:** or is that not what they're saying? Is it because of the wording "if and only if"? Does the theorem actually translate to:

- if $T$ is one to one, then $T(\vec{x}) = \vec{0}$ has only the trivial solution
- if $T(\vec{x}) = \vec{0}$ only has the trivial solution, then $T(\vec{x})$ is one to one

I can see both of these being true.

Comment: If $T(\vec x_1)=\vec b=T(\vec x_2)$ then $T(\vec x_1-\vec x_2)=0$.

Comment: And vice versa.

Comment: @lulu Would love a bit more clarification. I wrote that down, and here's what I got. Correct me if this is wrong: suppose $T(\vec{x_1}) = \vec{b}$ and $T(\vec{x_2}) = \vec{b}$. Then by linearity, $T(\vec{x_1} - \vec{x_2}) = T(\vec{x_1}) - T(\vec{x_2}) = \vec{b} - \vec{b} = \vec{0}$. So we have that $T(\vec{x_1} - \vec{x_2}) = \vec{0}$. Such a mapping is only one to one if $\vec{x_1} = \vec{x_2}$. This would in turn imply that $T(\vec{x_1} - \vec{x_2}) = T(\vec{0}) = \vec{0})$, or in other words, $T(\vec{x}) = \vec{0} $ only has the trivial solution.

Comment: @Bernard And if what I did is correct, how would I do the reverse? Re: your comment of "vice versa". Thanks!

Comment: I just meant it's an equivalence, not just an implication.

Comment: @Bernard Gotcha. Is the proof I wrote above rigorous and/or correct? Would I need to look at it from a second angle too?

Comment: Suppose we have shown that $T(\vec x)=\vec 0\iff \vec x = \vec 0$. We want to deduce that $T(\vec x_1)=T(\vec x_2)\iff \vec x_1=\vec x_2$.  But $T(\vec x_1-\vec x_2)=\vec 0\iff \vec x_1-\vec x_2=\vec 0 \iff \vec x_1=\vec x_2$ so we are done.

Comment: As @lulu commented, it's the linearity of T which ensures it comes down to proving $T(\vec x)=0\implies \vec x=\vec 0$.

Comment: @lulu I think I understand now. Thank you both. Though I'm curious: are there any flaws in the proof I posted above? It seems it's the same as yours, only a bit more verbose.

Comment: I find it hard to follow your proof.  What are you assuming?  I expect it is the same as mine, but you should make your assumptions explicit.

Comment: Right, okay, I agree. I think my proof is "assume T(x) = 0 only has trivial solution and show that it must be one to one". I was able to follow yours, though, so I'll go with that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $T$ is not one-to-one. Then there exist $a$ and $b$ with $a \neq b$ such that $T(a) = T(b)$. But then by linearity we have that $T(a-b) = 0$, and so there is a nontrivial solution to $T(x) = 0$. (Aside: it is the linearity that allows us to make broad statements and consider only the point $0$).

By the contrapositive of what we've just shown, we now have that $T(x)$ having no nontrivial solutions implies that $T$ is one-to-one.

Conversely, suppose that $T$ is one-to-one. Then as $T(0) = 0$, there can be no more solutions to $T(x) = 0$. So $T$ being one-to-one implies that there are no nontrivial solutions to $T(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Special thanks to @lulu and @Bernard in the comments. Gonna write up an answer.

The theorem is equivalent to:

- if $T$ is one to one, then $T(\vec{x}) = \vec{0}$ has only the trivial solution
- if $T(\vec{x}) = \vec{0}$ only has the trivial solution, then $T(\vec{x})$ is one to one

We need to prove both these cases to prove the theorem. In both cases, we'll assume $T$ is linear.

**1) if $T$ is one to one, then $T(\vec{x}) = \vec{0}$ has only the trivial solution**

We proceed with a direct proof. Assume that $T(\vec{x})$ is one to one. Then for $\vec{a}, \vec{b} \in R^n$, we have that $T(\vec{a}) = T(\vec{b}) \implies \vec{a} = \vec{b}$, by definition of one to one. Now, by linearity, we have that $T(\vec{a} - \vec{b}) = T(\vec{a}) - T(\vec{b}).$ Furthermore, since $\vec{a} = \vec{b}$ and $T(\vec{a}) = T(\vec{b})$, we can conclude that $T(\vec{a} - \vec{b}) = T(\vec{0}) = T(\vec{a}) - T(\vec{b}) = \vec{0}$. In other words, $T(\vec{0}) = \vec{0}$. This means $T(\vec{x}) = \vec{0}$ only has the trivial solution.

**1) if $T(\vec{x}) = \vec{0}$ only has the trivial solution, then $T$ is one to one**

We proceed with a direct proof. Assume that $T(\vec{x}) = \vec{0}$ only has the trivial solution. Then $\vec{x} = \vec{0}$. Let's take vectors $\vec{a}, {b} \in R^n$. Because $T(\vec{x})$ is linear, we have that $T(\vec{a} - \vec{b}) = T(\vec{a}) - T(\vec{b}) = \vec{0}.$ Rearranging, $T(\vec{a}) = T(\vec{b}).$ We now need to prove that this implies that $\vec{a} = \vec{b}$. we do so by noticing that since $T(\vec{x}) = \vec{0} \implies \vec{x} = \vec{0}$, then $T(\vec{a} - \vec{b}) = \vec{0} \implies \vec{a} - \vec{b} = \vec{0}$. Solving, we have that $\vec{a} = \vec{b}$, as desired.